# "Go To Definition" equivilent shortcut for interface implementations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, interface-implementation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you quickly find the implementation(s) of an interface's method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261567/how-do-you-quickly-find-the-implementations-of-an-interfaces-method)
>   [Go to definition on concrete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234796/go-to-definition-on-concrete-type)

Coding to interfaces is great until you want to quickly jump to a function implementation.

In the good ole days, F12 (Go to Definition) would take you straight there, but of course now it just takes you to the interface definition, not the implementation.

I appreciate that there could be multiple implementations, but is there a quicker way than manually finding the file, or Ctrl-Shift-F to search for all references, even though that includes every call too. "Find All References" gives the same result.

Just wondered if anyone had a handy method / macro?

Comment: Sorry guys. My searching clearly sucks. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It's Ctrl+F12 there. You'll be surprised how powerful it is...

By the way, it is called "Go to Implementation" in contrast to "Go to Declaration".

Comment: I use F-12, than Alt+End, may be it works without ReSharper?

Comment: In VS 2019 "Go to Implementation" (CTRL + F12) works without ReSharper.