# Why can't I find usages on an Interface (and methods) from an Referenced assembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, interface

I have an interface that I make use of within my application.  The interface definition is in a referenced assembly that I created:

```
// Assembly MyAssembly.dll, v1.0.0.0
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void MyMethod();
}
```

I make use of this interface within my application (a WPF project) like so:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

I can right mouse click and select `Find Usages` on `IMyInterface` just fine from any implementation of this interface within my project:

[image: OK]

However, if I navigate to `IMyInterface` (`Go To Declaration` or <kbd>F12</kbd>) and open the `Metadata` view, it doesn't allow me to find usages on either `IMyInterface` or on any of the method names, the option is greyed out!

[image: Greyed out]

This doesn't make sense. It may be from metadata, but I have just navigated from an implementation within my project to the interface definition within the referenced assembly.

Why can't I find usages of the interface name or interface methods and is there any way around it?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830659/visual-studio-2010-go-to-implemented-method-rather-than-interface

Comment: @RobbieDee I'm not sure that that gives any more info

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do it from metadata. If you want this option available you need to add this project to your solution.

Comment: How strange, this is a bit of a down side to creating an assembly out of your code.  Especially when it comes to splitting your interfaces out into a separate project, like with a service layer.

Comment: have you also created and used pdb-files ?

Comment: @nozzleman Good question!  I just checked the folder location of the assembly and there is indeed a `.pdb` in there.  Do I need to direct VS to that folder in some way?

Comment: i would check if it is in the output directory of your target solution. not sure if this would solve the issue though

Comment: @Coulton Do you use ReSharper? This would get you going in no time i guess.